# Login form not initializing not authenticating

Tags: python, html, django

When I was adding a template from the internet to my login.html code I encountered a problem. When I try to login it did not work. Even after I added CSRF tokens and login form control code. It has a clickable button that does not thing. I hope someone can help me. If any pictures or other codes needed please feel free to ask.

inn.html(login.html 1'this is a nickname'))

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}Login{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container">
<br/>   
<h1>Login</h1>

<br/> <br/>
<div class="form-group">
  <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button class="btn btn-secondary">Login</button>

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

login.html:

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
    {% load static %}
    
    {% block content %}
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'fonts/icomoon/style.css' %}">
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/owl.carousel.min.css' %}">
    
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
        
        <!-- Style -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    

      </head>
      <body>
      
    
      
      <div class="content">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 order-md-2">
    
              <img src="{% static 'images/undraw_file_sync_ot38.svg' %}" alt="Image" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 contents">
              <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                  <div class="mb-4">
                  <h3>Sign In to <strong>C</strong></h3>
                  <p class="mb-4">Lorem.</p>
                </div>
                <form method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username">
    
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" for="password" placeholder="Password">
                   
                  </div>
                    
                
                  <input type="submit" value="Log In" class="btn text-white btn-block btn-primary">
                  
                
                </form>
               
                </div>
              </div>
              
            </div>
            
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
        <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'js/popper.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'js/main.js' %}"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Please, also make sure all the files are in place and configured correctly [see](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/); 
Please, then, do this: 1. open developer tools; 2. Go to the "Network" tab; 3. try to submit a form and check if any action is called; 4. Go To Console and see if there is an error or no.

Comment: Remove the first `</form>` tag. As it is, your `submit` button is not inside your form.

Comment: @evergreen I just have done that

Comment: Did it work correctly before you added the template from the internet?

Comment: Oh yes it did. I actually have a copy of how how it looked before I added the template I just renamed it to inn.html. @evergreen

Comment: Btw @UtmostCreator. I do not understand your instructions I understood the first part and did not understand what you said after "Please, Then do this:" Sorry. I am new to these stuff.

Comment: @Kaushik can you please show the `inn.html` code so we will be able to see what was added?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235733/discussion-between-kaushik-and-evergreen).

Comment: Also can we please use the chat and I have just added the 'inn.html'

Comment: @UtmostCreator I have added it in my head does not seem to work.

Comment: Submit a form, and see what is inside the network tab. wheather it is submitted or not.

Comment: @UtmostCreator It sadly did not submit I got the same error with Jquery you said

Comment: @UtmostCreator what do you mean. (check discussion)

Comment: @UtmostCreator it did not work